# How to group by month-year from a differently formatted date (SQL)

Tags: sql, cryptography, blockchain

I've tried to self-teach myself SQL but am struggling with a dashboard I want to build.

How do I manipulate or change the date which is "08/03/18 09:00" so that I can group it by month+year and not per second?

[link to what the table looks like][image: 1]

my current attempt:

```
SELECT AVG(price) as "price", MONTH(minute) as month
FROM prices.usd
WHERE minute > now() - interval '365 days'
AND contract_address = '\x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f'
GROUP BY month
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  The correct way to store dates is using the native date/time data types in your database.  Why are you not using them?

Comment: @amateur_coder thanks! I'm getting this error: 

Error running query: column "month" does not exist LINE 3: SELECT AVG(price) as "price", DATEPART(month,minute) as mont... ^

Comment: @GordonLinoff , sorry i don't know what database i'm using -- but i'm running this on duneanalytics.com

Comment: Please use text or table markdown to display tables. here is [ASCII table](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) for easier generate proper table format.